# access Login name and login status from login control inasp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, login-control

Hell everyone....I am new to asp.net..I am really trying my best to achieves foll..
I have created a login control in asp.net.For Authentication i am writing function which authenticates the user gets the user name in session and redirect to another page.I am writing this function manually because i require username for future purpose

```
protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
    {
        Login Login1 = ((Login)LoginView1.FindControl("Login1"));
        string userName = Login1.UserName.ToString();
        Session["uname"] = userName;
        Response.Redirect("~/Project/Process/Process.aspx");
    }
```

Now what i want is when i redirect user to Process.aspx...
1)I want to display the Username from login control and status....if user is loggedin....then display contents of page and Logout link to logout the user....
2)if user is not authenticated redirect him to login page...

Please help me....any help would be really appreciated

Comment: Can you post the code for your Login control as well?

Comment: Did this answer below solve it for you?  If so, please mark the question as answered.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check that the user is authenticated on each page that you want to hide - in the `Page_Load()` method of those pages.  You don't need to store the value in the `Session` and you don't necessarily need your `Login1_Authenticate` method (unless you are doing some other processing upon authentication).

On any of your secure pages, in the `Page_Load()` method:

```
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == false)
    Response.Redirect("~/YourLoginPage.aspx");
```

Also, to redirect the user to a specific page after successfully logging in, use the `DestinationPageUrl` property of the `Login` control like so:

```
<asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" DestinationPageUrl="~/Project/Process/Process.aspx" />
```

To display the user name and status of the currently logged in (or not) user:

```
<asp:LoginView id="loginView" runat="server" >
    <LoggedInTemplate>
        <asp:LoginName id="loginName" runat="server" />&nbsp;
    </LoggedInTemplate>
</asp:LoginView>
<asp:LoginStatus ID="loginStatus" runat="server" LogoutText="Logout" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutPageUrl="~/YourHomePage.aspx" LoginText="Login" />
```

To get the currently logged in user name at any time in the future from any page, use:

```
string userName = User.Identity.Name;
```

Let us know if this gets you what you need.